# Algorithm problem about Google kick start round B 2021

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm solving the **longest progression problem in Google kick start 2021 Round B** using python.

Here is the link to the problem: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000435a5b

I have written the following code but it seems that there's always the wrong answer in a test case, I have tried all situations as far as I concerned, can someone give me the help that where's the problem in my code, thanks!

```
def solution(A, N):
    i, j = 0, 1
    ranges = {}
    res = 0
    left = {}
    right = {}
    while j < N:
        diff = A[j] - A[i]
        while j < N and A[j]-A[i] == (j-i)*diff:
            j += 1
        ranges[(i, j-1)] = diff
        left[i] = (i, j-1)
        right[j-1] = (i, j-1)
        if j <= N-1 or i > 0:
            res = max(res, j-i+1)
        else:
            res = max(res, j-i)
        i = j-1
    # check if two ranges can be merged
    for i in range(1, N-1):
        if i == 1:
            if i+1 in left:
                l1, r1 = left[i+1]
                if A[i+1]-A[i-1] == 2*ranges[left[i+1]]:
                    res = max(res, r1-l1+3)
        elif i == N-2:
            if i-1 in right:
                l1, r1 = right[i-1]
                if A[i + 1] - A[i - 1] == 2 * ranges[right[i - 1]]:
                    res = max(res, r1 - l1 + 3)
        else:
            if i+1 in left and i-1 in right and ranges[right[i-1]] == ranges[left[i+1]]:
                l1, r1 = right[i - 1]
                l2, r2 = left[i+1]
                if A[i+1]-A[i-1] == 2*ranges[left[i+1]]:
                    res = max(r1-l1+r2-l2+3, res)
    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    T = int(input().strip())
    for i in range(T):
        N = int(input().strip())
        A = list(map(int, input().strip().split(" ")))
        res = solution(A, N)
        print("Case #{}: {}".format(i+1, res))
```

Comment: Please link to the problem.

Comment: Here's the link about this: [link](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000435a5b)https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000435a5b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merging logic is incorrect. The code only tries to merge the entire ranges. In a simple failing case

```
1 2 3 6 5 4
```

it misses that replacing `6` with `4` would produce `1 2 3 4 5`.